# how can i install vmware 12.0 on windows 7 32 bits

Tags: vmware-workstation

Error : This installation package is not supported by your processor type. Contact your product vendor.

i get this error while installing vmware 12.0 on windows 7 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot!

"New System Requirements

While 32 bit operating systems are supported inside virtual machines, VMware Workstation 12 Pro and Workstation 12 Player require 64 bit processor and 64 bit host operating systems for advanced computing and enhanced performance."